# Changing the Color of the Events in Google Calendar by Checking Google SpreadSheet Column with Values "YES" to green & "NO" to red

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

The below code works perfectly, now i need to change the color of the calendar events conditionally. I'm new to this coding.  Can anyone edit this code for me please....

```
function CreateEvent() {
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('***<LINKTOCELLTHATHASCALENDARID>***').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('YOUR_CALENDAR_ID');
  var drg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,7);
  var dA=drg.getValues(); 
  var crg=sh.getRange(2,6,sh.getLastRow()-1,1);//save that event was created in column G
  var cA=crg.getValues();
  for (i=0;i<dA.length;i++) {
    var shift=dA[i];
    var title=shift[0];
    var startTime=shift[1];
    var endTime=shift[2];
    //var guests=shift[3];
    var description=shift[3];
    var location=shift[4];  
    if(!shift[5]) {
      var event={'location': location,'description': description +',','sendInvites': 'True'}
      eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, event)
      cA[i][0]="CREATED";//keeps this event from being created again
    }
  }
  crg.setValues(cA);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the value is in Column G:

```js
      var e = eventCal.createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, event);
      var b = shift[6];
      if (b === 'YES') { e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN); }
      if (b === 'NO') { e.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.RED); }
```

References:

[setColor(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#setcolorcolor)

[Enum Color](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/color)